# How would a fictional Slavic country in modern times survive the Soviet Union with their monarchy existing into modern times?

Tags: alternate-history

Basically, the story I'm working on is Princess Diaries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Diaries_(film) with a bit more murder and the country is called Belzova which is a Slavic country based on Ukraine and its culture that borders Ukraine as well as Romania (it is in the middle of the sea).

This is where the issue comes in because not only did the USSR basically take over a lot of Eastern Europe but a lot of the monarchies within Eastern Europe were deposed or forced to abdicate so my question is, how can I reasonably have Belzova, if not avoid the USSR, keep its monarchy into modern day?

Comment: put that in your question for people who have never heard of princess diares https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Diaries_(film)

Comment: also did you put Belzova in the middle of the sea? how can it border both bulgaria and Ukraine without taking Romania's/Moldavia's place?

Comment: You don't need to put it in the sea; just use the territory known as [Novorossiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novorossiya), which in real history was annexed by the Russian Empire gradually in the 18th century. (The bad news is that before that it was mostly *not* Slavic-speaking.) As a Romanian, the good thing is that if Novorossiya is a separate independent country then chances are that the Soviet Union never took Bessarabia so that to this day the eastern third of the historical Moldavia is still with Romania and not a separate country.

Comment: Would it work if the monarchy was restored after 1989?

Comment: It looks like you're wanting us to write over a century of history for you. Such a task is far to broad and opinion based to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: I wonder if government-in-exile scenario could work. I believe it would require the people to want it be restored as the de facto government after the Soviet "occupation".

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 Government-in-exile would definitely work and it is actually what I'm sort of leaning towards just for story purposes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answers assumes that Belzova occupies the territory known as [Novorossiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novorossiya). The question wants it somewhere in the north-western horn of the Black Sea, but on one hand there isn't all that much space there, and on the other hand changing *both* history and geography is too much.

Long story short, Belzova remained independent because it was never part of the Russian Empire. In WW2, it successfully defended Crimea against the Germans and managed to liberate its terriory before the ever helpful Red Army arrived on the scene. Throughout the Cold War, Belzova maintained good relationships with the Soviet Union, while at the same time making NATO aware that it was *not* a Soviet ally, but *could* be.

[image: Belzova, about 1897]

<sup>*Belzova, around 1897. Own work, based on the [map of Novorossiya](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:New_Russia_on_territory_of_Ukraine.png) by [Dim Grits](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Dim_Grits), available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license. Note that the cities called Yekaterinoslav / Dnepropetrovsk / Dnipro and Nikolayev / Mykolaiv in the real timeline are Sicheslav and Ingulsk in the alternative timeline, because they would have had no reason to adopt the names of Russian monarchs. The river crossing the country north-east to south-west is the [Dnieper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnieper).*</sup>

**Historical summary:** Belzova was created on the basis of a forward-looking alliance of the (Cossack) [Zaporozhian Sich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaporozhian_Sich) and the (Tartar) [Crimean Khanate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Khanate) at the beginning of the 18th century.

<sup>It all begins in 1708, when in real history Ivan Mazepa, Hetman of Zaporizhian Host, decided suddenly to switch sides and become an ally of Sweden and Poland against Russia. In the real timeline, he failed miserably. In the alternative timeline, instead of acting on impulse, he takes the time to convince both his Cossacks and his frenemies in the Tartar Crimean Khanate that this is the only possible course of action which could avoid annexation by the Russian Empire. As a result, instead of coming at the [Battle of Poltava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Poltava) with a token force of some 3000 Cossacks, he arrives on the field with a combined army of 15,000 Cossacks and Tartars. Instead of a crushing Russian victory the battle is fought to a draw; the [Great Northern War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Northern_War) ends not with a complete Russian victory but rather with a bevvy of treaties of convenience maintaining the status quo.</sup>

It successfully defended itself against the Russian Empire throughout the 18th century; in the 19th century it had a complex relationship with the Russian Empire, but was successful in maintaining its independence. It repelled a Soviet attack in 1921, and afterwards established relatively good relationships with the Soviet Union.

During the Second World War, it mounted a stubborn resistance against the German onslaught; it successfully defended Crimea throughout the war, and managed to counter-attack and liberate its territory before the Red Army arrived on the scene (1944).

After the war, Belzova maintained an ambiguous position between the Soviet Union and NATO; to the Soviet Union it offered unimpeded access to the Black Sea through the Straight of Kerch, as well as free-port access to Ingulsk and Odessa.

(The historical summary can be expanded upon request.)

**Royal family:** The kings of Belzova are Mazepids, descended from the famous [Ivan Mazepa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Mazepa), Hetman of Zaporizhian Host, Prince of the Holy Roman Empire, and his consort Hanna Polovets. (In real history the marriage was childless.)

**Languages spoken:** Cossack Russian (a conservative south-western dialect of Russian), and Crimean Tartar (a Turkic language). There is also a sizeable Greek minority in Crimea.

**Main cities:**

- Odessa;
- Ingulsk (real history Nikolayev / Mykolaif); Sicheslav (real history Yekaterinoslav / Dnepropetrovsk / Dnipro); Yuzovsk (real history [Donetsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donetsk)); Kalmiusk (real history [Mariupol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donetsk));
- Kezlev (in Crimea, real history [Eupatoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yevpatoria) / Yevpatoria); Aqmescit (in Crimea, real history [Simferopol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simferopol)); Aqyar (in Crimea, real history [Sevastopol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sevastopol)); and Kaffa (in Crimea, real history [Theodosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feodosia) / Feodosia).

**Main rivers**

- The [Dniester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dniester) marks the border with Romania.
- The (Southern) [Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Bug) crosses the country north to south and empties in the Black Sea neark [Ingulsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mykolaiv) (real history Nikolayev).
- The [Dnieper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnieper) is one of the most important rivers of Europe; it crosses the country north-east to south-west and empties in the Black Sea. The city of [Kherson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kherson) is located on the estuary of the Dnieper.
- The [Kalmius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalmius) marks the border with the Russian Empire / Soviet Union / Russian Federation. On the banks of the Kalmius lie the cities of Yuzovsk (real history Donetsk) and Kalmiusk (real history Mariupol).

**Economy:** Historically, the economy of Belzova was based on export of grain (most of the country lies in the [chernozem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernozem) belt of eastern Europe), fishing, and export of pearls (fished on the Crimean coast).

In the 19th century, the discovery of rich deposits of coal and iron ore around Sicheslav (= Yekaterinoslav / Dnepropetrovsk) and Yuzovsk (= Donetsk) (in the Donetsk Basin = Donbass), shared with Russian Empire) created the conditions for the rapid development of an industrial base.

Today, agriculture remains an important sector of the economy. Belzova produces high quality steel, used in part by its ship-building industry. The country is known (some would say, notorious) internationally for its software and services industry. The Crimean resorts attract a very large number of tourists from Russia and Romania, and also from lands farther away.

Comment: So a Finland with monarchy?

Comment: @FaitoDayo: Yes. Both Finland and Yugoslavia managed to survive close to the Soviet sphere without being submerged.

Comment: Wow this is really in-depth, thank you so much; though now after reflection for storyline reasons I'm thinking it might work better if Belzova was actually taken over by the USSR and simply had their monarchy restored after its fall, purely because the crown prince needs to have briefly spent time in Canada and married a woman there to have the secret princesses required in the story

Comment: @MzLish23 -- Could they simply send the CP to Canada as a means of protecting him by keeping him out of harm's way? Perhaps during a crisis when a new Soviet premier decides to get all expansionist?

Comment: @MzLish23: It is perfectly normal for princes to be sent abroad to be educated. Usually at a prestigious university. This prestigious university is usually one of the English Oxford and Cambridge, but it could have been a Candian university. It would be unusual for a prince *not* to be send at a prestigious university abroad.

Comment: This is so excellent.  And AlexP actually has another answer which would serve here and with the same historical chops:  [Rise of Siberian Russia](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/184943/would-it-be-possible-for-tsar-to-escape-execution-and-form-a-great-power-elsewhe/185003#185003) - a timeline where the tsar and his government escape the Bolsheviks and Imperial Russia continues in the East.